# Duplicate row in multi table join

Tags: mysql

I have four tables as below:

```
tenant
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | John Smith | 
|  2 | Anna Jones | 
+----+------------+

property
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | landlord_id | address       |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 |           1 | King Street 1 | 
|  2 |           1 | Green Grove 2 | 
|  3 |           2 | Queen Stree 3 | 
+----+-------------+---------------+

tenant_has_property
+-----------+-------------+
| tenant_id | property_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 | 
|         1 |           2 | 
+-----------+-------------+

landlord
+----+-----------------+
| id | name            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Best Homes Ltd. | 
|  2 | RealEstates Inc | 
+----+-----------------+
```

Now I would like to get a list of all tenants that rent a property from landlord id = 1

When I run a query like below:

```
SELECT 
  tenant.id, tenant.name 
FROM 
  tenant, property, tenant_has_property 
WHERE 
  tenant.id = tenant_has_property.tenant_id AND 
  tenant_has_property.property_id = property.id AND 
  property.landlord_id = 1
```

I am getting duplicate rows:

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | John Smith | 
|  1 | John Smith | 
+----+------------+
```

I know changing the query to

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT tenant.id, tenant.name ...
```

will remove duplicate rows, but my question is:

Is it possible to avoid using DISTINCT and construct JOINs in such a way that no duplicate rows will be returned? Already tried all combinations of INNER, LEFT JOINS without much luck :(

Any suggestions very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonh Smith is a tenant for two properties from Best Homes Ltd so he comes out twice, so you have to mess about with group by or distinct etc.

To get what you want without that you'd need another table say

Portfolio
Which would give you one record linking tentant to kandlord.
Then you could use that to link portfolio to property. ie you group up multiple tenancies, so you don't have to use the tennat_has_property table to see the relation.

Whether it's worth the restructure of the schema I've no idea.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Looks like I was trying to achieve the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

True version is

```
SELECT id, name FROM tenant 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT tenant_has_property.tenant_id FROM 
tenant_has_property 
WHERE tenant_has_property.property_id IN 
(SELECT property.id FROM property WHERE property.landlord_id = 1 )
)
```

I think that should work for you. But i didnt try it cause i dont have access to a sql server on my terminal.

Comment: unfortunatelly your query still returns duplicate rows.

Comment: @Chris can you provide me your create table scripts?

Comment: found it : SELECT name FROM tenant 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT tenant_has_property.tenant_id FROM 
tenant_has_property 
WHERE tenant_has_property.property_id IN 
(SELECT property.id FROM property WHERE property.landlord_id = 1 )
) just returns the name John Smith without DISTINCT ; )

Comment: Hmmm, this are two sub-queries, not a JOINs as per my original questions. The reason I don't like this solution is in real life my tenant and tenant_has_property tables has hundreds of thousands of rows and efficiency is very important. IMHO single SELECT with JOINs will be far more efficient compared to SELECT + 2x SELECT sub-queries as proposed by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following query using an `IN` clause:

```
  SELECT 
    t.id, t.name 
  FROM 
    tenant t 
  WHERE 
    t.id IN (
      SELECT
        thp.tenant_id 
      FROM 
        tenant_has_property thp
        INNER JOIN property p ON thp.property_id = p.id
      WHERE
        p.landlord_id = 1
    )
```

But I strongly suggest you not to use this method because inner SQL statements tend to run slower than JOIN queries. You can use `GROUP BY` to group the results by tenant.id.

```
  SELECT 
    t.id, t.name 
  FROM 
    tenant t 
    INNER JOIN tenant_has_property thp ON t.id=thp.tenant_id
    INNER JOIN property p ON thp.property_id = p.id
  WHERE 
    p.landlord_id = 1
  GROUP BY t.id
```

Achieving this with only JOIN statements is not possible as far as I know. Because MySQL will join the records as you requested and then will end up with following rows:

```
t.id,   t.name  , thp.tenant_id, thp.property_id, p.id, p.landlord_id,  p.address  
 1  , John Smith,       1      ,        1         , 1 ,       1      , King Street 1  
 1  , John Smith,       1      ,        2         , 2 ,       1      , Green Grove 2
```

Since you request only t.id and t.name fields, MySQL returns only that columns to you but it does not know that they have duplicate values. You either have to force it by adding `DISTINCT` to your select clause or telling MySQL how to group the records and return a single row.